# Adding elements to a dataframe while iterating over it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe called `SBPV_DBPV` which looks something like this:

```
    STUDY_ID    SBPV    DBPV
0   1        12.927571  19.054308
1   3        12.635492  10.603099
2   5        25.825786  7.663226
3   6        16.931817  12.369440
```

And I was trying to implement KMeans algorithm manually. So I have 3 centroids and I am trying to calculate distance of each row to these centroids and append the minimum centroid to the row in the dataframe:

```
for i, row in SBPV_DBPV.iterrows():
    #distance of each row to the 3 centroids
    dist1 = ((row['SBPV'] - (k1.values.reshape(-1,1)[0]))**2 + (row['DBPV'] - k1.values.reshape(-1,1)[1])**2)**0.5
    dist2 = (row['SBPV'] - (k2.values.reshape(-1,1)[0])**2 + (row['DBPV'] - k2.values.reshape(-1,1)[1])**2)**0.5 
    dist3 = (row['SBPV'] - (k3.values.reshape(-1,1)[0])**2 + (row['DBPV'] - k3.values.reshape(-1,1)[1])**2)**0.5 
    row['cluster'] = min(dist1,dist2,dist3)
```

However after I run the loop, the dataframe does not get modified. I had read that I have to use `.apply`in order to modify the dataframe but I dont know how I can implement that while iterating over the rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need change:

```
row['cluster'] = min(dist1,dist2,dist3)
```

to:

```
SBPV_DBPV.loc[i, 'cluster'] = min(dist1,dist2,dist3)
```

for assign by index values.